# Question about tropical semifield

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\text{Trop}(u_1,\dots,u_m)$ be an abelian group which is freely generated by the $u_j`s$, and written multiplicatively. We define $\oplus$ in $\text{Trop}(u_1,\dots,u_m)$ by
\begin{equation}
\displaystyle\prod_j u_j^{a_j}\oplus\prod_j u_j^{b_j}=\prod_j u_j^{\text{min}(a_j,b_j)}
,\end{equation}
and call $(\text{Trop}(u_1,\dots,u_m),\oplus,\cdot)$ a tropical semifield. I read that the group ring (ring being $\mathbb{Z}$) of $\text{Trop}(u_1,\dots,u_m)$ is the ring of Laurent polynomials in the variables $u_j$ but I don't understand how. Could someone explain/give a hint?

Comment: The statement you read probably refers to the usual multiplication of monomials, rather than to the operation $\oplus$ (whose monoid ring is not an integral domain, let alone a Laurent polynomial ring).

Comment: Ohh, yeah, of course. I completely misunderstood it, thanks!